# Bijection of transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, symmetric-matrices

Is there a bijection from a row vector x = [1xn] to a symmetric positive definite (SPD) matrix [n x n]?

Here is what I have:

1. C2 = x^T.x gives a n by n square matrix
2. C2 = 0.5(C2 + C2^T) [to make it symmetric]
3. C2 = C2 + epsilon * np.identity (C2.shape[0]) [ eigenvalues are all zero and positive so by adding this negligible epsilon, all eigenvalues are now positive ]

However, when I trace back, x^T.x will not be able to give a bijection.
Are there any other methods?

Comment: The space of $1\times n$ matrices (i.e. row vectors) has dimension $n$, while the space of symmetric $n\times n$ matrices has dimension $n(n+1)/2$. So for $n>1$, there may technically be set-theoretic bijections because they're the same cardinality, but there cannot be any polynomial-based bijection (ask an algebraic geometer why). Also note your step (2) is redundant because step (1) outputs a symmetric matrix.